# Extract only the text if column in excel has both number and text

Tags: excel-2010

I have below two values in two excel row,

A1 _DC_SUBMISSION_STATUS_REPORT_20141016105520.pdf
A2 _DC_VALID_TRX_20141016105519.pdf

My expect result is
B1 _DC_SUBMISSION_STATUS_REPORT_
B2 _DC_VALID_TRX_

Need a formula for above requirement, Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","|",   LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","")))))
```